# Prevent Android Phone from shutting down on long power button press

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, oneplusthree

I am using One Plus 3 running OxygenOS 4.0.3.When I long power button on my phone it shutdown. I want to avoid this. I tend to shutdown my phone accidentally many times without realizing it. Especially when its in my pocket

Comment: Probably should ask it on OnePlus forum.

Answer (score 0):

Put your phone in sleep mode after some idle time. Most of the phone will just awake the phone when long power button press.

Go to Settings --> Display --> Sleep --> enable time delay.

Comment: I was not talking about Locking the phone